# Python2.7: ImportError: six 1.3 or later is required; you have 1.2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, six

Got this error when importing matplotlib.pyplot. But I have checked the version of six installed using `pip list`, and it returns version 1.9.0. And when I checked `six.__version__`, it returns 1.2.0.

Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a bug somewhere, but a quick and dirty work around was the following:

`pip install six==1.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

Check you're using the correct version of `pip` that refer the correct Python version by issuing following command:

```
pip -V
```

The command will show the Python version the `pip` is using and the path of `pip` package.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing, the cause was a left over six.pyo / six.pyc in my PYTHONPATH dir which was imported instead of the installed version.